# How to get new connection object in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session, connection

Hibernate use sessions to interact with the database, then what is the use of connection pool?
As per the configuration, hibernate default connection pool size is 1. If we open multiple sessions(as per the default configuration each session is a thread - current_session_context_class) in the hibernate, all those sessions will use the same connection object? If not what is the use of taking new connection in hibernate and how to get that new connection object?